# pandas `to_numeric` integer downcast cast floats not to integer

Tags: python, pandas, casting

With this sample dataframe:

```
>>> d = pd.DataFrame({'si': ['1', '2', 'NA'], 's': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

>>> d.dtypes
#
si    object
s     object
dtype: object
```

### My first attempt was to use astype and the 'Int64' NA aware int type, but I got a

traceback

```
>>> d.si.astype('Int64')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-ed289e0c95aa> in <module>
----> 1 d.si.astype('Int64')
...
```

### then I try the `to_numeric` method:

pandas `to_numeric` integer downcast cast floats

```
In [112]: d.loc[:, 'ii'] = pd.to_numeric(d.si, errors='coerce', downcast='integer')

In [113]: d.dtypes
Out[113]: 
si     object
s      object
ii    float64
dtype: object

In [114]: d
Out[114]: 
    si  s   ii
0    1  a  1.0
1    2  b  2.0
2   NA  c  NA
```

In the above I expect to have `ii` column with integers and integer nan

Documentation say:

```
downcast : {'integer', 'signed', 'unsigned', 'float'}, default None
    If not None, and if the data has been successfully cast to a
    numerical dtype (or if the data was numeric to begin with),
    downcast that resulting data to the smallest numerical dtype
    possible according to the following rules:

    - 'integer' or 'signed': smallest signed int dtype (min.: np.int8)
    - 'unsigned': smallest unsigned int dtype (min.: np.uint8)
    - 'float': smallest float dtype (min.: np.float32)
```

Comment: The key word is **_possible_**. With `errors='coerce'`, you expect things to get set to `NaN`, which is a float, so that's the smallest type possible. If you want you can `.astype('Int64')` to make it the nullable integer type

Comment: Thank you @Alollz, I've updated my question to illustrate that .astype on this simple dataframe traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `pandas` is still adapting/transitioning to fully supporting integer `NaN`. For that, you have to explicitly convert it to `Int64` after your `pd.to_numeric` operation.

No need to downcast.

```
# Can also use `'Int64' as dtype below.
>>> pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').astype(pd.Int64Dtype())

# or

>>> pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
```

---

```
0       1
1       2
2       3
3    <NA>
Name: col, dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `errors='coerce'` set, and the documentation for that option says (emphasis mine):

> `errors` : {`'ignore'`, `'raise'`, `'coerce'`}, default `'raise'`
>
> - If `'raise'`, then invalid parsing will raise an exception.
> - **If `'coerce'`, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.**
> - If `'ignore'`, then invalid parsing will return the input.

Since your `si` column contains `NaN`s, you can't convert it to an integer column because `NaN` is a float, and therefore all other values in the column are upcasted to the `float64` dtype.